# Salesforce popout custom link base url

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to assign a base url to this popout. Currently the popout is sitting in a managed package page so whenever I visit `/apex/mypage` it is running under the managed package domain prefix (e.g. `c2g.cs65.force.com/apex`) and bombs out.

When I manually hardcoded the url as `cs65.force.com/apex/mypage` it worked just fine. I know in formulas and visualfoce I could just do something like `$site.baseurl` but that doesn't seem to work here.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. You need to do `/apex/c__mypage` in order to get it. The `c__` is critical for base domain url pointing.